# Connecting a string input to a switch with charAT

Tags: java

I've been stuck on an assignment that I've been working on for a few days (note I'm totally new to java so I'm still learning from the ground up.) I'm trying to make an algorithm that reads the given text file and prints out how many of each vowel there is as well as consonants. It must follow these rules
Read the text from the file AdventuresInWonderland.txt.
Use a single while loop to read the lines of the file.
Use a single for loop to iterate over the characters in each line.
Use a single switch statement to determine which counter to increment.

I've made it this far but I can't figure out what I've done wrong I'm specifically having issues around the vowels = line.charAt(count)
Any tips or help would be extremely appreciated.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
File file = new File("AdventuresInWonderland.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

int countA = 0;
int countE = 0;
int countI = 0;
int countO = 0;
int countU = 0;
int countConsonants = 0;
char vowels;
int count;

while (sc.hasNext()) {
  String line = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
  
  for (count = 0; count < line.length(); count++);
  }
    vowels = line.charAt(count);
    switch(vowels)
      {
        case 'a':
          countA++;
          break;

        case 'e':
          countE++;
          break;

        case 'i':
          countI++;
          break;

        case 'o':
          countO++;
          break;

        case 'u':
          countU++;
          break;

        case 'b':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'c':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'd':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'f':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'g':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'h':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'j':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'k':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'l':
          countConsonants++;
          break;
          
        case 'm':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'n':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'p':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'q':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'r':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 's':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 't':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'v':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'w':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'x':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'y':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

        case 'z':
          countConsonants++;
          break;

          
      }
        System.out.println ("Vowels found: ");
        System.out.println ("a: " +countA);
        System.out.println ("e: " +countE);
        System.out.println ("i: " +countI);
        System.out.println ("o: " +countO);
        System.out.println ("u: " +countU);
        System.out.println ("Consonants: " + countConsonants);

}
    }
```

Comment: Might I suggest you rework your `switch` statement? As it stands now, it doesn't look very pretty (i.e. there's a cleaner way to check for non-vowels than the way you've written it). Also, does the `for` loop actually do anything, and should your `while` loop really end where it ends? ;)

Comment: @fireshadow52 For the for loop I think I'm trying to move the program through each character one at a time until it reaches the end. I appreciate the advice on re-examining where my while loop is closed though, I'll try and make some alterations.

Comment: Jhanzaib spoonfed you a solution below, but your `for` loop was doing nothing because you ended it with the `;` on the end of the line. You closed the `while` loop too early, and because of that, your code actually wasn't processing any of the lines.

Comment: 'vowels' is not a good variable name. Personally I would filter anything not a letter out

Comment: @fireshadow52 and while lI appreciate him giving me the answer down below I'm going to use your advice and try and fix it for myself. So i'ts important that my switch statement is inside the while loop? It seems like a lot of the issues are coming back to me closing things off from other loops too early.

Comment: @KrissStone Yeah, the `switch` needs to be inside because you need to do the conditional checking on all of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    File file = new File("AdventuresInWonderland.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    int countA = 0;
    int countE = 0;
    int countI = 0;
    int countO = 0;
    int countU = 0;
    int countConsonants = 0;
    char vowels;
    int count;

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        for (count = 0; count < line.length(); count++) {
            vowels = line.charAt(count);
            switch (vowels) {
                case 'a' -> countA++;
                case 'e' -> countE++;
                case 'i' -> countI++;
                case 'o' -> countO++;
                case 'u' -> countU++;
                case 'b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'k', 'm', 'r', 'p', 'l', 'n', 'q', 't', 'v', 's', 'w', 'j', 'x', 'y', 'g', 'z', 'c' -> countConsonants++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println ("Vowels found: ");
    System.out.println ("a: " +countA);
    System.out.println ("e: " +countE);
    System.out.println ("i: " +countI);
    System.out.println ("o: " +countO);
    System.out.println ("u: " +countU);
    System.out.println ("Consonants: " + countConsonants);

}
```

The main problem was some misplaced parenthesis, which lead to your while and for-loops not doing anything. I also replaced the switch statements with an enhanced version.

Edit: Here is how I would do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    File file = new File("AdventuresInWonderland.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    HashMap<String,Integer> countLetters = new HashMap<>();

    countLetters.put("a",0);
    countLetters.put("e",0);
    countLetters.put("i",0);
    countLetters.put("o",0);
    countLetters.put("u",0);
    countLetters.put("consonants",0);

    char vowels;
    int count;

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        for (count = 0; count < line.length(); count++) {
            vowels = line.charAt(count);
            switch (vowels) {
                case 'a','e','i','o','u' -> countLetters.put(String.valueOf(vowels),countLetters.get(String.valueOf(vowels))+1);
                case 'b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'k', 'm', 'r', 'p', 'l', 'n', 'q', 't', 'v', 's', 'w', 'j', 'x', 'y', 'g', 'z', 'c' -> countLetters.put("consonants",countLetters.get("consonants")+1);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println ("Vowels found: ");
    char[] allVowels = new char[]{'a','e','i','o','u'};
    for (char c: allVowels){
        System.out.println (c +": " + countLetters.get(String.valueOf(c)));
    }
    System.out.println ("Consonants: " + countLetters.get("consonants"));
}
```

The other method works fine as well.

Edit2: Try using this instead:

```
switch (vowels) {
    case 'a':
      countA++;
      break;

    case 'e':
      countE++;
      break;

    case 'i':
      countI++;
      break;

    case 'o':
      countO++;
      break;

    case 'u':
      countU++;
      break;

    case ' ':
    case '.':
    case ',':
        break;
    default:
        countConsonants++;
        break;
}
```

Default is the one that runs if you don't find any match on any of the cases. Here I add the cases for `.`,   and `,` because they probably exist in the book and are not consonants. You might need to add `;`, `:` excetra if the book has a lot of other type of characters. However, in that case I would recomment just using your method, just slightly modified. Replace the lines

```
case ' ':
case '.':
case ',':
    break;
default:
    countConsonants++;
    break;
```

in the code above to

```
    case 'b':
    case 'c':
    case 'd':
    case 'f':
    case 'g':
    case 'h':
    case 'j':
    case 'k':
    case 'l':
    case 'm':
    case 'n':
    case 'p':
    case 'q':
    case 'r':
    case 's':
    case 't':
    case 'v':
    case 'w':
    case 'x':
    case 'y':
    case 'z':
      countConsonants++;
      break;
```

Comment: The issue I run into here is that it claims multi consistent case labels aren't working in my version of java, this is another problem I was having earlier which is why it was SO long.